# Dealing with correlated predictors when using LASSO

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression, predictive-models, lasso

I am developing a prognostic index using the LASSO technique and wondering how to deal with the highly correlated predictor variables. Should I choose the ones I want to include in the LASSO a priori or is the LASSO programmed to select the best/better of highly correlated predictors variables?
thanks.

Comment: That is one of LASSO inherit weakness. You could probably use elastic net to make use of a ridge penalty to make feature slightly "more uncorrelated". This post on: [How does LASSO select among collinear predictors?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56282)  is rather enlightening too, I think.