# Feature filtering with LASSO and cross validation

Tags: self-study, feature-selection, lasso

In a linear regression problem, $y = (y_1, \cdots, y_{80})$ is the response, $X = (x_1, \cdots, x_{80})$ is a $4500 \times 80$ matrix of predictors. $k = (k_1, \cdots, k_{4500})$ is the vector of regression coefficients.

I want to select $2$ features out of the $4500$ highly correlated features, so I attempt to do a feature filtering with LASSO in the first place. Then, for the reduced feature space, I can afford to perform the best subset selection.

The question is I don't know whether the number of features $M$ that I should keep after filtering is a hyperparameter. I read somewhere that if the size of the feature space exceeds $40$, it will be impractical to do the best subset selection. However, I don't know whether this applies to my case.

On the other hand, I learned that LASSO is unstable for feature selection (**But I don't know what does this mean, and references will be appreciated**). So it comes to me with no explicit reason that I should decide this $M$ through LOOCV.

Should I decide this parameter through LOOCV? If I should not, then how large the $M$ that I should choose?

Comment: I've tried to answer some of your interrogations - but your question as it is probably contains too many questions to receive a specific answer. I would suggest looking for other stackexchange posts related to feature selection and LOOCV which will cover most of the points you mention here

Comment: @Xavier Bourret Sicotte I have read those references in your answer and I find them really helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> LASSO is unstable for feature selection

The combination of LASSO and Cross Validation isn't *always* unstable for feature selection. Factors leading to instability are:

- More features than data points:
- Highly correlated features: see [How does LASSO select among collinear predictors?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56282/how-does-lasso-select-among-collinear-predictors?rq=1)

> But I don't know what does this mean, and references will be appreciated

Intuitively, a stable algorithm is one for which the prediction does not change much when the training data is modified slightly.

Here are a few references on algorithmic stability

- [Variance of $K$-fold cross-validation estimates as $f(K)$: what is the role of "stability"?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/280665/)
- http://math.arizona.edu/~hzhang/math574m/Read/LOOtheory.pdf
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_(learning_theory)