# What happens to Lasso Regression when variables are collinear? How do we deal with it?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, self-study, lasso, multicollinearity

I'm self-studying the Elements of Statistical Learning and I came across this question [image]

I believe that rather than a single solution, there's now a manifold of solutions with $\hat{\beta}_j + \hat{\beta}_j^* = \hat{\beta}_j^{(original)} = a$.

From a pictoral perspective, originally we'd have the likelihood of the dataset intersect at a single point (see left):
[image]
But if $\beta_2$ corresponded to a duplicated variable, then we'd have that the likelihood contour should perfectly line up with the edge of the diamond and there's no single optimal solution.

What is the lesson here? **I'm not sure what I'm supposed to take away from this problem.**

Furthermore, it seems like certain numerical optimization procedures for lasso regression such as least angles regression - which iterates one variable at a time - might permanently set one of the duplicated pair's coefficient to zero anyways?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you get the take-home point quite well.

With collinear predictors, LASSO and other variable-selection methods necessarily make arbitrary choices about which to include. The perfect collinearity in this example is extreme, but the problem arises with less extreme multicollinearity. See [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/56282/28500) among many on this site; e.g., search for [`lasso bootstrap instability`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=lasso+bootstrap+instability).